Why don't Emacs' Org Mode's Babel buffer-wide header arguments work in this simple example?
The manual for Org Mode distributed with Emacs 29.4 reads:
   The following example makes all the R code blocks execute in the same
session.  Setting ‘:results’ to ‘silent’ ignores the results of
executions for all blocks, not just R code blocks; no results inserted
for any block.

     #+PROPERTY: header-args:R  :session *R*
     #+PROPERTY: header-args    :results silent

However, I write an org mode file:
#+PROPERTY: header-args    :results silent

#+begin_src elisp
  (print "Hello")
#+end_src

And when I run C-c C-c on the block, results are printed!
#+RESULTS:
: Hello

Why?

[emacs.se] is the appropriate place to ask about using Org-mode.

The buffer must be killed then reopened for changes in global properties to take effect. Just a M-x revert-buffer will work too.

You can refresh the existing buffer by doing C-c C-c on the #++PROPERTY: line. You don't need to kill or revert (but those will work as well of course).
